# Storing head() data in python | pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, machine-learning, jupyter

How to store dataframes generated from head() methods in python and how to access them ?
I have arrived at this line of code :

```
df1.head(n=66)
```

But i need to access data shown by this method as :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JyEkS.png)

Comment: `df = df1.head(n=66)` ?

Comment: Ok, it works but data doesn't get stored in dictionary format. Do you have any method for doing that ?

Comment: `d = df1.head(n=66).to_dict()` ?

Comment: thank you sir, didn't knew it works on dataframe as well.